# print XOR elements from the indices ranging from x to y (XOR Range)

Tags: python-3.x, time-complexity, bitwise-xor

If I have some array like `[2,6,2,9,7,4]` I am finding Xor of given range from left to right.it will work for small input but give time complexity error for large input.

```
#Python Code for Xor Range

from functools import reduce
from operator import xor
arry=[2,6,2,9,7,4]
print(reduce(xor,arry[left:right]))
```

please help to solve time complexity error for larger input like 10^9.[problem link](https://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/xoring-ranges-1-4a2b7724/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ress = [0]
rese = [0]
b=input().split()
if b[0]=='1':
  ress.append(ress[-1]^int(b[1]))
elif b[0]=='2':
  rese.append(rese[-1]^int(b[1]))
else:
  l = int(b[1])
  r = int(b[2])
  n = len(ress)-1
  val = 0
  if l <= n:
    val ^= ress[n-l+1]
  else:
    val ^= rese[l-n-1]
  if r<=n:
    val ^=ress[n-r]
  else:
    val ^=rese[r-n]
    print(val)
```